# Не применяется цвет фона

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь установить цвет фона для `EditText` , делаю так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_focused="true"><shape>
    <solid android:color="#e74c3c" />
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#f1c40f" />
    <padding android:bottom="12dp" android:left="12dp" android:right="12dp" android:top="12dp" />
</shape></item>
<item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
    <solid android:color="#e74c3c" />
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#f1c40f" />
    <padding android:bottom="12dp" android:left="12dp" android:right="12dp" android:top="12dp" />
</shape></item>
```

но цвет фона EditText в приложении не меняется, хотя в Eclipse показано что изменен, вот скриншот[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

стиль для компонента я указал `android:background="@drawable/edit_text_reg"`

Comment: Вам надо просто изменить фон или на определенные состояния?

Comment: @ВиталийОбидейко просто фон

Comment: попробуйте для начала project-clean сделать, бывает что xmlресурсы тупят и не передаются, у меня было пару раз.

Comment: @EvgenyKaravashkin на это не похоже. все меняется кроме фона

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение Вашей проблемы кроется в том, что нет item'a(состояния) `по умолчанию`.

Добавьте **в конец** xml-файла Вашего селектора следующий код:

```
<item><shape>
       <solid android:color="#BAD" />
       <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#f1c40f" />
       <padding android:bottom="12dp" android:left="12dp" android:right="12dp" android:top="12dp" />
</shape></item>
```

> Еще раз обращу внимание на то, что добавлять данные строки необходимо именно **в конец** селектора. Если добавить к примеру в начало, то никакие другие состояния не активируются.

**UPD:**

Привожу полный код селектора, который в данный момент **точно** работает.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
        <solid android:color="#e74c3c" />

        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#f1c40f" />

        <padding android:bottom="12dp" android:left="12dp" android:right="12dp" android:top="12dp" />
    </shape></item>
<item android:state_focused="true"><shape>
        <solid android:color="#e74c3c" />

        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#f1c40f" />

        <padding android:bottom="12dp" android:left="12dp" android:right="12dp" android:top="12dp" />
    </shape></item>
<item><shape>
        <solid android:color="#BAD" />

        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#f1c40f" />

        <padding android:bottom="12dp" android:left="12dp" android:right="12dp" android:top="12dp" />
    </shape></item>

</selector>
```

Comment: к сожалению это не решило проблему. Цвет фона не изменился. А если в компоненте  EditText указать `android:background="#мой_цвет"` -цвет фона меняется, но при этом нет всего остального, что установлено в селекторе, а мне без этого не как

Comment: @Денис обновил, ну и если и щас не заработает, то я х3, что у Вас там творится)

Comment: Большое спасибо. Но я так же делал. Ваш ответ верный, все появилось после перезагрузки Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Так как вам нужно изменить фон, то сделайте так:

```
<item><shape>
    <solid android:color="#e74c3c" />
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#f1c40f" />
    <padding android:bottom="12dp" android:left="12dp" android:right="12dp" android:top="12dp" />
</shape></item>
```

Comment: ну так по сути у меня так и есть, только в разных состояниях. почему же он не меняется?

Comment: Удалите состояния и посмотрите)))

Comment: мне нужны состояния для того чтобы изменять цвет обводки

Comment: Но у вас не указано обычное состояние! И попробуйте в XML разметке указать элементам clicable = true и focusable = true

Comment: убрал все состояния, сделал так как вы сказали - фон не изменился

Comment: А у вас в xml файле есть в конце строчка </selector>?

Comment: да, конечно есть